# Solaris jdk 7 installation error java -version No such file or directory

Tags: bash, solaris, java, jdk

Am trying to follow [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/thefield/entry/solaris_11_jdk_installation) website for instruction on how to install jdk for Solaris 10 with the following information:

```
$ isainfo -v
64-bit amd64 applications
        ssse3 tscp sse3 sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov amd_sysc cx8 tsc fpu
32-bit i386 applications
        ssse3 tscp sse3 sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu
```

When I enter the following command java -version after following the instruction i get an error.

```
$ java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

Can anyone help out. Thanks

**Below are the steps i have taken**

```
$ ls -l
total 14
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     bin          512 Sep 17 11:17 instances
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other          7 May 12 14:21 j2sdk1.4.2_34 -> ../j2se
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         18 May 12 14:22 jdk1.5.0_32 -> instances/jdk1.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         18 May 12 14:21 jdk1.6.0_37 -> instances/jdk1.6.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          22 Sep 17 11:20 jdk1.7.0_67 -> instances/jdk1.7.0_67/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          11 Sep 18 09:42 latest -> jdk1.7.0_67
drwxr-xr-x   8 root     bin          512 May 12 15:04 packages
$ rm latest
$ ln -s instances/jdk1.7.0_67 jdk1.7.0_67
$ ln -s jdk1.7.0_67 latest
$
$ pwd
/usr/jdk
$
$ cd /usr/
$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x  43 root     sys         1024 Sep 18 09:45 .
$ ls -ld java
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          10 Sep 18 09:43 java -> jdk/latest
$ pwd
/usr
$ rm java
$ ls -ld java
java: No such file or directory
$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x  43 root     sys         1024 Sep 18 10:24 .
$
$ ln -s jdk/latest java
$ java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

**Update**

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/bin:/usr/ant/apache-ant/bin:/u01/oracle/middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/bin:/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin


Error
    $ java -version
    bash: java: command not found
```

**Update 2**
other export output ommitted

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin
$ export path
$ export
declare -x ANT_HOME="/usr/ant/apache-ant"
declare -x HOME="/"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/java"
declare -x JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
declare -x PATH="/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/bin:/usr/ant/apache-ant/bin:/u01/oracle/middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/bin:/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin"
declare -x PWD="/usr/java/bin/amd64"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
$ java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

Comment: `echo $PATH` and what error you have when you install it?

Comment: hi braiam, thanks for answering please see update

Comment: umm... yeah, `/usr` isn't in your path, try `/usr/java -version` instead, it should work. Also, you shouldn't install binaries directly on `/usr` but `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: $ /usr/java -version
bash: /usr/java: is a directory ... still doesn't work. hmmm... ok so is it ok if I move my existing jdk7 directory to usr/bin ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a convoluted answer to your question because I believe you are making things **way** more complex than they need to.

I have a pretty good guess on what is wrong with your install: Referring to my bullet point below about 64-bit Java on Solaris I'm guessing that what you're doing wrong is that you've *only* installed the 64-bit Java overlay package for Solaris. That won't work.

Ok, now that I got your attention (:-)) please indulge me why I believe you're on the wrong path all together.

I'm not sure I would follow that blog you're referring to. In my experience Solaris itself can spin up a Java process (Registration tool background process, Web Console, Common Agent Container and what have you. Nothing vital really, but still ) and changing the system-wide Java may be a bad idea ..or at least it leaves you with less control on a per-application basis. Simply leaving the system Java alone is a *much simpler* approach, IMHO.

Here are my highly opinionated guidelines for how to handle Java on Solaris:

- General: As a system professional never take anything from
  [java.com](http://java.com). It's for consumers/desktops. Always use [Java on
  Oracle Tech Network
  site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) (I still use
  the http://java.sun.com link which I'm sure will continue to work for
  the next 10 years :-))
- Leave the system-wide Java alone. Let it live its own life.
- Unpack Java packages into `/opt/java` or `/apps/java` or whatever. Somewhere *you* control and that feels natural to you. Let's call it `JAVA_ROOT` from now on.
- As you unpack those packages from `java.sun.com` into `JAVA_ROOT` it will eventually look like this in terms of sub-dirs (example):

```
jdk1.7.0_05
jdk1.7.0_09
jdk1.7.0_17
jdk7 -> jdk1.7.0_17
jre -> jre7
jre1.6.0_32
jre1.7.0_05
jre1.7.0_17
jre1.8.0_20
jre6 -> jre1.6.0_32
jre7 -> jre1.7.0_17
jre8 -> jre1.8.0_20
```

- Notice how I use symlinks. Well, you get the picture.
- When you start your application you simply (in the startup of that application) set the `PATH` to point to the Java you want. Some applications also want you to set a `JAVA_HOME` var. Now you can control things on a per-application basis. If you use the symlinks in your application startup scripts you can still retain some system-wide change ability when you need it. If your application requires a specific version of Java then let it point to a specific version and not to one of the symlinks.
- An important note on 64-bit systems: Up until and including Java 7 you have to install *two* packages from java.sun.com on top of each other as the 64-bit support is effectively delivered as an overlay package to the 32-bit package. This confuses most people as it is different from all other OSes. Even if you don't want to use 32-bit Java you first need to put in the 32-bit Java package and then overlay it with the 64-bit Java package. Luckily this has changed in Java 8 because Oracle no longer delivers 32-bit Java for Solaris.

The obvious drawback of this solution is that you'll miss out on the benefits of using a package manager for the Java software. I believe the benefits far outweigh the drawbacks. Judge for yourself.

Even on Solaris 11 (which has an excellent package manager for software) I still favor this solution.

Comment: Hi Nolan, thanks for the tips i'll give it another shot. Good thing I had a snapshot of that Solaris box before i changed the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin
export PATH
```

and give it another shot.

Comment: Hi Harvinder, i tried ur suggestion but it still doesn't work. Please see update 2

Comment: Do you know where you installed Java? From your question so far, it's hard to tell. `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin` seems like the only place. Post the result of `cd /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67` followed by `ls -l`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   3 10       143          512 Jul 26 00:32 bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          18 Sep 18 09:42 jdk1.7.0 -> instances/jdk1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          21 Sep 18 10:22 jdk1.7.0_67 -> instances/jdk1.7.0_67
drwxr-xr-x   4 10       143          512 Jul 26 00:32 jre
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          10 Sep 18 09:45 latest -> jdk/latest
drwxr-xr-x   4 10       143          512 Jul 26 00:32 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 10       143          500 Jul 26 00:32 release

Comment: i placed my java here directory here after unzipping -  /usr/jdk/instances/

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the installation. Just to verify that, cd into `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin` and `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin` and try running `java -version` from both places.

Answer (score 0):

In Solaris, The `java` command commonly (but not always) refers to `/usr/bin/java`. `/usr/bin/java` is usually a symbolic link to the installed `java` binary.

E.g., on one of my Solaris systems:

```
dev:/ which java
/usr/bin/java
dev:/ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         16 Nov 19  2013 /usr/bin/java -> ../java/bin/java
dev:/
```

Having it as a symbolic link makes it easy to install another version of Java. Just change the `/usr/bin/java` link to the newly installed version's `java` binary, and it will use the new version. If you need to revert back to the old version, the symbolic link can be changed back to its previous value very quickly.

To set up the link if it doesn't already exist:

```
ln -s <path to java binary that you wish to use> /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: tried this one it doesn't work to. What's strange is if I goto the directory itself where i unzip jdk7 (/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/amd64) and execute java -version from that folder it will say java command not found

Comment: `./java -version` probably will work if you are in the directory `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/amd64`. Otherwise it is still going through your`PATH` variable which probably doesn't include `/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/amd64` or `.` (The current working directory.